# Using gems via Rubygems in windows - path failure

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have installed ruby 1.9.3, with RubyInstaller and DevKit. I installed the required gem I'm looking forward to use, but no matter what I do i can't get it working. I run my program and i get the following runtime erro:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gnuplot-2.6.2/lib/gnuplot.r
b:59:in `gnuplot': gnuplot executable not found on path (RuntimeError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gnuplot-2.6.2/
lib/gnuplot.rb:74:in `open'
        from cluster.rb:182:in `<main>'
```

What have i done wrong? I did try to add `require rubygems`, run `:cmd>> ruby -rubygems ...(params)...`, I installed the gem via `gem install gem_name` in the curent working directorie, but i can't make it find my gems.

PS: I encounter this problem on windows OS.

Solution addition: the path C:....\gnuplot.exe must be added to the PATH variable

Comment: It looks like it is finding the gem and loading it. Notice that the error is inside one of the files of the gem. When you installed the gem, did it compile correctly? Did you get any errors?

Comment: Nope. I can run gem install again and give you the otput

Comment: D:\ai>gem install gnuplot
Successfully installed gnuplot-2.6.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for gnuplot-2.6.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for gnuplot-2.6.2...

Comment: What command are you using to execute your gem?

Comment: execute how?  i don't get it i just require it in the file... is what not the way it should work?
`require 'rubygems'
require 'csv'
require 'gnuplot'`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask how you were trying to use it. You listed a command so I thought you were trying to call it from the command line.

Comment: ah no, i ment that i tried witht eh flag, the gem is used in the  programs body

Comment: This may seem like a silly question but, do you have GnuPlot installed on your system? Not the gem but the actual application the gem is a wrapper for.

Comment: omg, do i need that :S ?, it makes sense now, sorry but i had no clue, i was supposing the gem is independent :S, jsut a drawing tool or smthing...

Comment: I've posted it as an answer for future people that might search for this issue on Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [gnuplot gem](https://github.com/rdp/ruby_gnuplot) is just a wrapper for the actual [gnuplot application](http://www.gnuplot.info/). This means that the application needs to be installed in order for the gem to work.

Your error mentions line 59 of `/lib/gnuplot.rb` which is an error raised when the gem attempts to find your system's installation of gnuplot. For Windows, it is looking in your PATH system variable.

If you do not have gnuplot installed prior to using the gem, you can download and install it from its [SourceForge files page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/).

Answer (score 1):

[From Gnuplot's Rubyforge site:](http://rgplot.rubyforge.org/)

"If the gnuplot executable for your system is called something other than simply 'gnuplot' then set the RB_GNUPLOT environment variable to the name of the executable. This must either be a full path to the gnuplot command or an executable filename that exists in your PATH environment variable."

I'm guessing the problem is that executables in Windows end with an .exe extension, so the program is looking for something just called 'gnuplot' and isn't finding it. You can try to set RB_GNUPLOT to the full path of the executable on your system. I've had to set environment variables in Windows before, it's possible; just google the solution for you particular OS.